# Show excerpt on the same page post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How do I show the excerpt in the same post is page?

Example:

```
<?php
if ( the_excerpt() != '' ) {
echo $my_excerpt; 
}
?>
```

But this does not work!

Answer (score 1):

[the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt) will echo the excerpt and [get_the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) will return it. So try something like this:

```
<?php
  $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
  if ( $my_excerpt != '' ) {
    echo $my_excerpt; 
  }
?>
```

Comment: This does not work, but this works well:
<?php echo get_post($post_id)->post_excerpt; ?>